# How can to send a calendar invite using sendgrid?

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am trying to send a calendar invite using SendGrid and when the email comes in, the invite is an .ics attachment. I would like the invite to be displayed already.

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4ndP.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPWUe.png)

This is how I am currently to adding the calendar:

$email->addContent("text/calendar", $mimeMessage);

**$mimeMessage is set to the message below:**

```
From: <from@someemail.com>
    To: <to@someemail.com>
        Subject: Program Calendar Event
        MIME-Version: 1.0
        Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset="UTF-8"
        Message-ID: 2797a6bab44c7188e16e6e2408b02a4a.somedomain.com
        \r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

        BEGIN:VCALENDAR
        PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
        VERSION:2.0
        METHOD:REQUEST
        X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
        BEGIN:VEVENT
        LOCATION:123 Hill Top
        DESCRIPTION:..
        DTEND:20190122T123000Z
        DTSTAMP:20200207T145155Z
        DTSTART:20190122T103000Z
        ORGANIZER;CN=Calendar Invitation - Nariel :mailto:info@someemail.com
        PRIORITY:5
        SEQUENCE:0
        SUMMARY:Program Calendar Event
        TRANSP:OPAQUE
        UID:dd0dd7668a8065f322975099ac26bb06.somedomain.com
        X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
        END:VEVENT
        END:VCALENDAR
```

This vcalendar syntax works when sending through MailGun and SparkPost. I am now trying to implement a solution using SendGrid.

I also tried setting $mimeMessage only to the vcalendar and got the same results.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
        PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
        VERSION:2.0
        METHOD:REQUEST
        X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
        BEGIN:VEVENT
        LOCATION:123 Hill Top
        DESCRIPTION:..
        DTEND:20190122T123000Z
        DTSTAMP:20200207T145155Z
        DTSTART:20190122T103000Z
        ORGANIZER;CN=Calendar Invitation - Nariel :mailto:info@someemail.com
        PRIORITY:5
        SEQUENCE:0
        SUMMARY:Program Calendar Event
        TRANSP:OPAQUE
        UID:dd0dd7668a8065f322975099ac26bb06.somedomain.com
        X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
        END:VEVENT
        END:VCALENDAR
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks to be a long issue ticket here https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/250

Comment: Quote from ticket - Could you please try? $attachment->setType('text/calendar; method=REQUEST');

Comment: Also from the ticket (at the bottom) I was also able to send calendar events and get them parsed by gmail with:

$mail->addAttachment(
                    new \SendGrid\Mail\Attachment(
                        base64_encode('ICS_CONTENT_HERE'),
                        "text/calendar; method=REQUEST",
                        "invite.ics",
                        "attachment",
                        "attachment"
                    )
                );

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the addContent to include ;method=REQUEST.
So it became: $email->addContent("text/calendar;method=REQUEST", $mimeMessage); and everything is working as desired.

Comment: No worries, just goes to show sometimes a good google can often give you your answer

Answer (score -1):

```
    public function build()
{
    return $this
      ->from(getenv('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), getenv('MAIL_FROM_NAME'))
      ->subject($this->subject)
      ->view('mails.calendar')
      ->attachData($this->ics, 'meeting.ics', [
                 'mime' => 'text/calendar; charset=UTF-8; method=REQUEST',
            ]);
}

public function sendInvite($to_name, $to_address, $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $location, $company)
{
    $domain = 'domain.com';

    $ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
    'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
    'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
    'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
    'TZID:Tokyo Standard Time' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
    'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
    'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
    'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
    'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
    'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
    'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
    'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
    'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
    'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
    'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
    'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
    'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART;TZID="Tokyo Standard Time":'.$startTime. "\r\n" .
    'DTEND;TZID="Tokyo Standard Time":'.$endTime. "\r\n" .
    'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
    'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
    'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
    'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
    'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
    'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
    'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
    'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
    'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
    'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
    'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
    'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";

    $data=[
        'name'=>$to_name,
        'company'=>$company,
    ];
    $email = new Calendar($subject, $ical, $data);
    return Mail::to($to_address)->send($email)->getDebug();
}
```

I have used Laravel to implement the same use-case. I created a Mailable object and included the above code in the build funtion. `$this->ics` contains my iCal text. Attaching the calendar content as a mime is the key here.
The build function is used to contruct the e-mail by the Laravel. The same procedure can be followed without using Laravel too.
Credits: https://dev.to/arxeiss/adding-events-to-calendar-automatically-from-email-1h0a

Comment: Please share more details. How does this code relate to the given question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @NicoHaase
I'm sorry for not being specifc enough. I have updated my answer and included more details so please have a look.